# How to _actually_ delete a DOM node via javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I don't want to remove an element from it's parent (via element.parentNode.removeChild). I want it to not exist in the DOM whatsoever.

Here's my use case. I have a [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) script I wrote which is supposed to delete annoying pop ups for me. For example, on [this page](https://data.triplebyte.com/who-y-combinator-companies-want-c1880a08ac88#.qvsze95rc) when I hover over the second sentence in point #2, a pop up appears. I want my script to delete that node so that it never pops up.

Here's the problem. Even if I remove it, the element still exists and the website's scripts will move that element into document.body again every time. I want the element to actually not exist. Not merely exist without a parent element.

Comment: It's like garbage collection. Remove all references to it, delete it, and bam. Non-existant

Comment: your question's title has nothing to do with the actual question. What you are really asking is how to stop an ad from being displayed on 3rd party website

Comment: @Sterling except it doesn't. When I call parentNode.removeChild, then hover back over the triggering text, the node pops up again

Comment: removing things from the DOM has nothing to do with the website's javascript injecting new elements to the DOM whenever it wants.

Comment: I have no problems being curious about javascript and also giving context. I don't think having both of those goals is mutuall exclusive

Comment: When you remove an element, it's gone. It sounds like your hover event is creating this node, or retains a reference to it in a variable. But when you removeChild, it's gone.

Comment: so if element.parentNode returns null, that's the definition of "not in DOM"? because the data structure exists in memory still after calling removeChild, even though parentNode is null. My reason for thinking this is that my script assigns it to a global variable. After calling removeChild, I call that global variable in console, and it shows me that data. so it exists still in memory in some fashion, even though parentNode is null

Comment: remove/removeChild completely removes an element from the DOM, however, any references to it that are still in scope (like the function that you're running) will still hold that Element in memory. It's not until you leave that scope that the Element will disappear entirely from existence.

Comment: ok. So the answer is that it's probably being referenced by a variable. that's why it appears in console after removeChild.

Comment: That's probably correct, yes

Comment: It's like if you have an array of objects: You can remove the object from the array, but if someone has access to the object, he can simply insert it again.
If the element isn't re-created on the fly and it's the same one, you can tamper with *its* structure and empty it of children. That's one way to go about it.